# Custom logic doesnt trigger before the base action "APPROVE"

Tags: acumatica

When I do a custom logic before the APPROVE in requisition screen, it seems like the logic is triggered after. My code is as below.

```cs
public PXAction<RQRequisition> action;
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Actions")]
[PXButton]
protected virtual IEnumerable Action(PXAdapter adapter,
    [PXInt][PXIntList(new int[] { 1, 2 }, new string[] { "Approve", "Reject" })] int? actionID,
    [PXBool]bool refresh,
    [PXString]string actionName)
{
    if (adapter.Menu == "Approve")
    {
        SIApprovalInfo.updateNextApprover(this.Base);

    }
    return Base.action.Press(adapter);
}
```

and I tried this action **without calling** the `return Base.action.Press(adapter);`

Sample code:

```cs
public PXAction<RQRequisition> action;
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Actions")]
[PXButton]
protected virtual IEnumerable Action(PXAdapter adapter,
    [PXInt][PXIntList(new int[] { 1, 2 }, new string[] { "Approve", "Reject" })]int? actionID,
    [PXBool]bool refresh,
    [PXString]string actionName)
{
    if (adapter.Menu == "Approve")
    {
        SIApprovalInfo.updateNextApprover(this.Base);

    }
    return adapter.Get();
}
```

Still the document is getting approved somehow. So where exactly is this approval getting triggered? How can I add my custom logic before that action?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a workaround which would be the create your own action, add it to the menu and depending on your business logic, call the Approval. Here is the basic snippet you could use :

```cs
using PX.Data;
using System.Collections;

namespace PX.Objects.RQ
{
    public class RQRequisitionEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<RQRequisitionEntry>
    {
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            Base.action.AddMenuAction(CustomApprove);
            CustomApprove.SetEnabled(true);
        }

        public PXAction<RQRequisition> CustomApprove;
        [PXButton]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Custom Approve")]
        protected virtual IEnumerable customApprove(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            PXCache cache = Base.Caches[typeof(RQRequisition)];
            var requisition = Base.Document.Current;
            if (Base.Approval.Approve(requisition))
            {
                requisition.Approved = true;
                yield return Base.Document.Update(requisition); ;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new PXInvalidOperationException(PXLocalizer.Localize("Approval failed"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```